# Previewing Meteor app via Nitrous.io cannot access local host port 3000

Tags: meteor, nitrousio

Running Mavericks on Macbook air, Nitrous box with simple test app bundles and runs fine on Meteor host but is not accessible on browser via 'preview'.

Bit baffled. No firewall running and unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same problem with Nitrous.io right now. I am betting this is an intermittent problem. A few hours ago I could access sites running on that box just fine from my local machine.

[Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) tells me:
`No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 54.217.184.231:80` so this points to a server-side problem. Seems we have to wait.

Comment: This was indeed an intermittent issue and the wonderful folks at Nitrous.io have fixed the problem.